# do events registered with angular.element get removed by $destroy?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've read that angular listeners (`$scope.$on`) are automatically removed by $destroy. And I've also read that outside event handlers like jQuery (`$(document).on`) need to be manually removed.

Does anyone know where angular.element falls into this paradigm?

A team member wrote something like `angular.element(document).on('event', () => );`. Do I need to manually remove this event in `$onDestroy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[angular.element (jqLite)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) is is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows AngularJS to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. `jqLite` implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint.

[Directive link functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom) which use it to attach event listeners to elements other than the directive's own element need to unregister those listeners when the directives element is destroyed.

```
function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {

    $document.on('event', documentEventHandler);

    scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
        $document.off('event', documentEventHandler);
    });

    function documentEventHandler(event) {
        console.log(event.target);
        //other code here
    });
}
```

To facilitate unit testing, inject the [AngularJS $document Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) instead of using `angular.element(document)`.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer.